# read.table, data.frame

Tags: r, data.frame

Tento realizar este trecho abaixo e ocorre:

```
rain.df<-read.table("C:\\Users\\Marcia\\Desktop\\Sript R\\daily.dat", header=TRUE)
```

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
>    linha 3572 não tinha 29 elementos.

Por quê ?
grato desde já

Comment: Talvez dê com `fill = TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

Um arquivo `.dat` é geral e pode ser estruturado em forma de texto/dados. O que acontece no seu caso, é que as opções `default` de `read.table` não lêem o arquivo de forma correta. Segue o que você pode fazer:

1º) Usar `readLines` para ler o arquivo e entender como o mesmo está estruturado. Com isso, você consegue verificar, por exemplo, se é necessário pular linhas antes de ler o arquivo (argumento `skip`, que pode ser o seu caso) e qual é a forma de separação dele.

Exemplo:

```
> readLines("https://docs.ufpr.br/~giolo/CE063/Dados/Hemophilia.txt", n=10)
 [1] "\"d1\" \"d2\" \"d3\" \"L\" \"R\" \"Low\" \"Medium\" \"High\"" "0 1 0 7 20 1 0 0"                                            
 [3] "0 1 0 9 12 0 0 1"                                             "0 1 0 9 20 1 0 0"                                            
 [5] "1 0 0 0 25 1 0 0"                                             "0 0 1 57 0 1 0 0"                                            
 [7] "0 1 0 23 26 1 0 0"                                            "0 1 0 8 21 1 0 0"                                            
 [9] "0 1 0 1 6 0 0 1"                                              "0 0 1 55 0 0 0 0"
```

Aí fica claro que a primeira linha é o cabeçalho, e as demais os dados. Ainda, as colunas são separadas por espaço. Dessa forma, para realizar a leitura, basta:

```
> read.table("https://docs.ufpr.br/~giolo/CE063/Dados/Hemophilia.txt", skip = 0, header = T, sep = " ")
    d1 d2 d3  L  R Low Medium High
1    0  1  0  7 20   1      0    0
2    0  1  0  9 12   0      0    1
3    0  1  0  9 20   1      0    0
4    1  0  0  0 25   1      0    0
5    0  0  1 57  0   1      0    0
6    0  1  0 23 26   1      0    0
7    0  1  0  8 21   1      0    0
8    0  1  0  1  6   0      0    1
9    0  0  1 55  0   0      0    0
10   0  0  1 55  0   0      0    0
```

Se tu fornecer o arquivo `.dat` eu edito a resposta, mas o procedimento é o mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Isso costuma ocorrer quando os dados que você está lendo possui uma linha com menos elementos do que as demais. Por exemplo, se você tem várias linhas, todas com 29 elementos (como colunas de uma tabela), e uma dessas linhas não está completa (por exemplo, uma delas possui apenas 2 entradas), você obterá um erro deste tipo.
Para corrigir, você pode proceder de duas maneiras:

1. Garantir que o arquivo que está tentando ler está completo e no formato desejado. Essa solução pode ser ok para um volume pequeno de dados ou quando o problema está na primeira ou ultima linha do arquivo, porém é uma solução longe do ideal;
2. Como o colega Rui Barradas comentou, a solução mais ideal seria utilizar o parâmetro `fill = TRUE`. Assim, a leitura deve ser feita da seguinte maneira:

   `rain.df<-read.table("C:\\Users\\Marcia\\Desktop\\Sript R\\daily.dat", header=TRUE, fill = TRUE)`

Fonte: [R_Manual Read.table](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html)